# Source code or binaries? How important is this?

Tags: binaries

Most open source projects provide precompiled binaries for a variety of platforms in addition to the source code. How important is it to download the source code and compile it yourself?

Are there security risks or performance problems with using downloaded binaries? Are they significant enough to worry about for non-business users?

Comment: I think this is two questions in one

Comment: This seems like a question more suited to [security.se].

Comment: @congusbongus would you prefer to see the security and performance questions as separate posts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more about the personal security of the user than open-source in general, although the question only tends to arise in an open-source context.

Comment: I **do** think there's a different (and relevant) question hiding in there though ...

Comment: @kdopen I'd be happy to ask it separately and edit it out of this one if I know which one it is... :)  Do you mean the performance question?

Comment: The more we can separate questions out the more we can tell what the community wants to be closed and what the community wants to be on topic.

Comment: I just asked it. It was actually more from the providers side, whereas yours is talking as a user of a FLOSS project.

Answer (score 5):

Well, without source code it isn't open source.

The availability of source code allows for others to change the code, one of the main reasons to have open source in the first place. Without source code it isn't longer possible.

If you only intend to use the software, the differences between using precompiled binaries and compiling yourself are:

- You can check the source code for unwanted code and compile it to be sure it has no backdoors. You can't be sure with the binary.
- Compiled specifically to your platform (CPU, OS-version etc.) the code might perform a bit better than a generic binary.
- You can apply patches from sources other than the maintainer.
- You can fix minor bugs that affect your usage.
- You can remove parts you don't need and complicate usage, add security risks or hamper performance.

The last points already go in the area that you change the code, but still under the premise that you want to use the software. It seems if the code is available for change the line between using software and working on software can become unclear.

Comment: "the difference between using precompiled binaries and compiling yourself is small". Care to explain that to the people who use and develop MacPorts and Homebrew? :)

Comment: Homebrew doesn't care about anything that is a GUI application, though, and wants you to install precompiled binaries for those.

Comment: @kdopen: You're right, it was to late, my answer bad. I edited it, removed the opinion and added reasons for using the code if you want to use the software. I hope that's better.